# How to get xml by url (AsyncTask, android)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the the following classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        XmlManager xm = new XmlManager();
        Log.i("tag",documentToString(xm.getXmlFromUrl("http://domen.com/abc/timelist.xml")));
    }
    //................
}

public class XmlManager {
    public Document getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        GetXmlTask txt = new GetXmlTask();
        txt.execute(url);
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = txt.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Log.i("tag", "test");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return doc;
    }
    //................
}

public class GetXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, org.w3c.dom.Document> {
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... arg0) {
          String url = "";
              if( arg0.length > 0 ){
                  url = arg0[0];                
              }

              Document doc = null;
          try {
            doc = stringToDom(convertStreamToString(new URL(url).openStream()));
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return doc;
    }
    //................
}
```

Unfortunately, I do not understand where the error exists. I see in LogCat (no filters):

> 01-24 17:47:44.194: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded drawable resource
>   varies with configuration!! 01-24 17:47:44.204: W/Zygote(37):
>   Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080446
>   (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_inline_error_above_holo_light.9.png) that
>   varies with configuration!! 01-24 17:47:44.284: W/Zygote(37):
>   Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080447
>   (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_inline_error_holo_dark.9.png) that varies
>   with configuration!! 01-24 17:47:44.294: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded
>   drawable resource #0x1080448
>   (res/drawable-mdpi/popup_inline_error_holo_light.9.png) that varies
>   with configuration!! 01-24 17:47:46.315: W/Zygote(37): Preloaded
>   drawable resource #0x10802ec
>   (res/drawable-mdpi/ic_lockscreen_outerring.png) that varies with
>   configuration!! 01-24 17:47:48.644: A/BatteryStatsImpl(93): Caused by:
>   libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory) 01-24 17:47:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(93): Error reporting
>   WTF 01-24 17:47:48.714: E/AndroidRuntime(93):     at
>   android.util.Log$1.onTerribleFailure(Log.java:103) 01-24 17:47:56.774:
>   E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg 01-24
>   17:47:56.774: E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg 01-24 17:48:03.064:
>   W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10005, 1)
>   failed with errno -2 01-24 17:48:11.094: D/StrictMode(190):   at
>   com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SpnOverride.loadSpnOverrides(SpnOverride.java:61)
>   01-24 17:48:11.094: D/StrictMode(190):    at
>   com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SpnOverride.(SpnOverride.java:43)
>   01-24 17:48:12.592: E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 01-24 17:48:12.592:
>   E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   01-24 17:48:12.592: E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 01-24 17:48:12.592:
>   E/SoundPool(93): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   01-24 17:48:12.592: E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 01-24 17:48:12.592:
>   E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg 01-24 17:48:12.592:
>   E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg 01-24 17:48:12.592:
>   E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg 01-24 17:48:12.592:
>   E/SoundPool(93): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg 01-24 17:48:12.982:
>   W/AudioService(93): loadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
>   01-24 17:48:20.262: A/NetworkStats(93): Caused by:
>   libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory) 01-24 17:48:24.822: D/StrictMode(190):     at
>   com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmDataConnectionTracker.getPreferredApn(GsmDataConnectionTracker.java:2276)
>   01-24 17:48:28.822: A/NetworkStats(93): Caused by:
>   libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory) 01-24 17:48:30.883: D/MmsSmsDatabaseHelper(190): [MmsSmsDb]
>   hasAutoIncrement: CREATE TABLE threads (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
>   AUTOINCREMENT,date INTEGER DEFAULT 0,message_count INTEGER DEFAULT
>   0,recipient_ids TEXT,snippet TEXT,snippet_cs INTEGER DEFAULT 0,read
>   INTEGER DEFAULT 1,type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,error INTEGER DEFAULT
>   0,has_attachment INTEGER DEFAULT 0) result: true 01-24 17:48:38.492:
>   W/MediaScanner(412): Error opening directory
>   '/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure/', skipping: Permission denied. 01-24
>   17:48:44.462: I/ActivityManager(93): Start proc com.svox.pico for
>   broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=541 uid=10024
>   gids={1015} 01-24 17:48:51.142: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93):
>   setKernelCountSet(10041, 1) failed with errno -2 01-24 17:48:55.792:
>   W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10005, 0)
>   failed with errno -2

Filter by application name:
There is void in LogCat.

Filter by tag "tag":

> 01-24 17:48:03.064: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93):
>   setKernelCountSet(10005, 1) failed with errno -2 01-24 17:48:51.142:
>   W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10041, 1)
>   failed with errno -2 01-24 17:48:55.792:
>   W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(93): setKernelCountSet(10005, 0)
>   failed with errno -2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if the XML file is not being parsed correctly for use in your application. One possible solution to fix this is to create a proper XML parser and then use it to loop over all the nodes in your file in the `AsyncTask`. Here is an example of a parser I created:

- [XMLParser](https://gist.github.com/4626337)

Next, all you have to do is use the parser to get the DOM elements and push the information where ever you want to display it in the `onPostExecute()` method. Here is a sample,

```
........

private class LoadExampleTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // code here
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            Void... params) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(); // the parser create as seen in the Gist from GitHub
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_VENUE);

        // looping through all song nodes <venue>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            map.put(KEY_LOCATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOCATION.toString()));
            map.put(KEY_TAGS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TAGS.toString()));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_LARGE_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_LARGE_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            exampleList.add(map);
        }

        return exampleList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter = new YourExampleAdapter(getActivity(), exampleList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

........
```

Also, this is an example the structure of the XML file used for this approach, but any structure should be fine, as long as you are mapping the keys correctly:

```
<venues>
    <venue>
      <id></id>
      <title></title>
      <location></location>
      <tags></tags>
      <description></description>
      <thumb_url></thumb_url>
      <thumb_large_url></thumb_large_url>
    </venue>
</venues>
```

Hope this helps to fix your error.